# Access --ask-become-pass value in task

Tags: ansible

Is there a way to access the value passed to the prompt when the flags `--ask-become-pass` or `-u` are used?
The objective is for the following task to check whether privilege escalation is correctly set up:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: become_pass
- debug:
    var: ansible_remote_user
- name: Fail if no become_pass is set
  ansible.builtin.fail:
    msg: "User {{remote_user}} is not root and become password is not set. Try using '--ask-become-pass' when executing this playbook."
  when: remote_user != 'root' and become_pass is not defined
```

The output:

```
TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [my-host] => {
    "become_pass": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [my-host] => {
    "ansible_remote_user": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

TASK [Fail if no become_pass is set] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [my-host]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'remote_user != 'root' and become_pass is not defined' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (remote_user != 'root' and become_pass is not defined): 'remote_user' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/usr/src/ansible/playbooks/setup-gitlab-runner.yml': line 25, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n        var: ansible_remote_user\n    - name: Fail if no become_pass is set\n      ^ here\n"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this information is not available at a playbook level, the flag `--ask-become-pass` being just an indicator for the Python script to prompt the user for the password, what you could do instead is to run a dummy task, with an escalation, rescue it, and prompt the user for the right course of action.

For example, the block:

```yaml
- block:
  - name: Test privilege escalation
    shell: echo
    changed_when: no
    become: yes

  rescue:
    - fail:
        msg: |-
          User `{{ _user }}` is not sudoer and no escalation was provided.
          Try using '--ask-become-pass' when executing this playbook.
      vars:
        _user: "{{ lookup('env','USER') }}"
```

Will fail on my user `demo`, with the message:

```
TASK [Test privilege escalation] *********************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  module_stderr: |-
    sudo: a password is required
  module_stdout: ''
  msg: |-
    MODULE FAILURE
    See stdout/stderr for the exact error
  rc: 1

TASK [fail] ******************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  msg: |-
    User `demo` is not sudoer and no escalation was provided.
    Try using '--ask-become-pass' when executing this playbook.
```

Otherwise, it will go through with:

```
TASK [Test privilege escalation] *********************************************
ok: [localhost]
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution, thank you! If I could upvote more than once, I would

Answer (score 0):

Considering the documentation for [become](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html) you could hardcode required credentials into the playbook via [Ansible Vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html#vault). If one were to not posess the correct vault file containing the encoded credentials, playbook execution would fail.